# gcc4.8 install using brew on Mac 10.6.8

Tags: macos, homebrew, gcc4.8

So I'm trying to install gcc4.8 via homebrew on my mac that's running on 10.6.8.

I tried following this guide
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38222/how-do-i-install-gcc-via-homebrew
but I can't seem to get it to work.

First I ran

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install gcc48
```

It downloads the file but then it does

```
make bootstrap
```

and I get

```
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [charset.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-libcpp] Error 2
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
```

if anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate some help :)

Comment: I know nothing about homebrew, but I'm certain more information is required to solve this.  You need to show the reason for those errors.

Comment: I would if I know what I was looking for but that is all the output that I get. As the guide says it should just be those two commands to get it runnin'.

Comment: If homebrew is anything like macports then there will be log files saved somewhere. Read the homebrew docs to find out where.